# How to get index of a 2d array of 2 similar structure ones with same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry the title may not present well.

I got two 2d arrays with similar structure.

array A:

```
arrayA[0]['account_name'] = 'a0';
arrayA[1]['account_name'] = 'a1';
arrayA[2]['account_name'] = 'a2';
```

And array B:

```
arrayB[0]['account_name'] = 'a1';
arrayB[1]['account_name'] = 'b0';
arrayB[2]['account_name'] = 'c0';
arrayB[3]['account_name'] = 'a0';
arrayB[4]['account_name'] = 'd3';
arrayB[5]['account_name'] = 'e8';
arrayB[6]['account_name'] = 'a3';
arrayB[7]['account_name'] = 'b4';
arrayB[8]['account_name'] = 'b1';
```

Now I know arrayA[0]['account_name'] equals to "a0", how can I search efficiently to check if it also exists in array B / know its position in array B? And I would like to loop for all values in array A.

Comment: Firstly these are arrays of objects, secondly - provide normal, readable code.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [
 { name: 'a0' },
  { name: 'a1' },
  { name: 'b2' }
];
const b = [
 { name: 'a0' },
  { name: 'a1' },
  { name: 'a2' },
  { name: 'b0' },
  { name: 'b1' },
  { name: 'b2' }
];

a.forEach((aa, i) => {
    let found;
    b.forEach((bb, j) => {
      if(aa.name === bb.name) {
       found = {
          index: j,
          value: aa.name
        };
       return true;
      }
    });
    console.log(found);
});
```

Comment: strange use of `filter()` just to iterate array and do nothing with return